# Angular HttpClient returns undefined instead of an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

So I have an API (which returns JSON) setup and it prints out a message that the users are getting fetched, but my console.log in angular of data returns undefined... Is it mandatory for my use-case to use an Interface or is a model like I use completely fine??

Bonus points if you also check out my error handling and point out mistakes with it.

My BackEnd service ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

const SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

@Injectable()

export class AviorBackendService {

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) { }
  UserData: any;

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
/**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  /**
   * Log a failed AviorBackend error.
   * @param message - message of the operation that failed
   */
private log(message: string) {
  throw new Error(`AviorBackend: ${message}`);
}

  getUserCollection() {
    return this.client.get<User[]>(SERVICE_URL + 'users');
  }
  // Get user
  getUser(firstname: User): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}user/firstname/${firstname}`;
    return this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {};
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }

 /*  addUser() {
    return this.client.post(SERVICE_URL + 'user', this.UserData, this.httpOptions);
  } */

  // Add student
  addUser(data: User): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}user`;
    return this.client.post(API_URL, data)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError())
      );
  }


  // Update User
  putUser(loginId, data: User): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}update/${loginId}`;
    return this.client.put(API_URL, data, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }
  // Delete student
  deleteUser(id): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}delete-student/${id}`;
    return this.client.delete(API_URL).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }
}
```

My User model ts:

```
import { Role } from './role';

export class User {
    id?: number;
    mandator?: number;
    loginId?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    password?: string;
    eMail?: string;
    group: string;
    role: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

My users component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AviorBackendService } from '../services/avior-backend.service';
import { UserCollection } from '../models/user-collection.model';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItem: string;

  users: UserCollection;
  user: User;
  firstname: string;
  selectedUser: User;

  constructor(private aviorBackend: AviorBackendService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.aviorBackend.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.users = data['users'];
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }

  clickItem(firstname) {
      this.aviorBackend.getUser(firstname).subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.selectedUser = data['user'];
      console.log(this.selectedUser);
    });
  }
}
```

```
<div class="list-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="list-header">Element overview</p>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filter" class="lb-sm">Filter</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="filter" id="filter">
    </div>

   <select size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (click)="clickItem(firstname)">
      <option *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
      </option>
    </select>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="content-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="selectedUser?.id">

  <p>Element contents {{selectedUser?.id}}</p>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="lb-sm">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstName" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.firstName">
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

My user-collection.model.ts:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export class UserCollection {

    user: User[];

}
```

Comment: In your browsers network tab is the response showing a value?

Comment: If you use a class, you should instantiate it, but it is better to define it as an interface.

Comment: @JasonWhite yes, it does.

Comment: @Silvermind how do I instantiate it? I'd rather pick the simpler solution.

Comment: The simple solution is to change `class User` to `interface User`

Comment: This looks weird: `this.selectedUser = data['user'];`. Does the response contain a `user` field?  Perhaps debug by `console.log(data)`

Comment: @Silvermind I changed the class to interface, it didn't solve the problem. no there is user field in the object as you can see from the model

Comment: which service method is returning undefined?

Comment: @JasonWhite getUser() and getUserCollection()

Comment: If I add console.log(data); to it it returns an array with the requested objects!

Comment: I never said that changing it to an interface would solve your problem, it is just good practice for return types of a httpclient call. Anyway: Your solution is according to your last comment: `this.users = data`;

Comment: @Silvermind I get the following error if I do so: `ERROR in src/app/avior/users/users.component.ts(25,7): error TS2741: Property 'user' is missing in type 'User[]' but required in type 'UserCollection'.`

Comment: In `getUser` the firstName variable has not been set by `users.component` so that call is going to fail. Also, in `AviorBackendService.getUser()`, you're expecting `firstname` to be of type `User`.

Comment: @JDunken how do I fix it?

Comment: Initialize the value of firstname in onInit to a blank string and once you have the correct data set it. In the `getUser` function, change `getUser(firstname: User)` to `getUser(firstname: string)` To fix the error you just posted, log the result of that call to the console and verify that its structure is what you think it is.

Comment: @JDunken `Property 'user' is missing in type 'User[]' but required in type 'UserCollection'.` Please also check out the newly added (which I forgot about) user-collection.model.ts